# Real spectrum nonempty iff exists $(n-1)$-dimensional invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-subspace

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $V$ be a real finite-dimensional vector space, $\dim V = n$, and $A : V \to V$ a linear map.
>
> $A$ has a nonempty (real) spectrum if and only if there exists an $A$-invariant subspace $W\leq V$ such that $\dim W = n-1$.

$\fbox{$\impliedby$}$

Assume there exists an $(n-1)$-dimensional and $A$-invariant subspace $W \leq V$. Pick a basis $\{w_1, \ldots, w_{n-1}\}$ for $W$, and extend it to a basis $\{w_1, \ldots, w_{n-1}, z\}$ for $V$.

The matrix representation of $A$ in this basis is:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \ldots & a_{1,n-1} & a_{1,n}\\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \ldots & a_{2,n-1} & a_{2,n}\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
  a_{n-1,1} & a_{n-1,2} & \ldots & a_{n-1,n-1} & a_{n-1,n}\\
  \hline
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_{n,n}
\end{array}\right]$$

We see that $Az = a_{n,n}z$. Furthermore, $a_{n,n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \ne 0$ imply $a_{n,n} \in \sigma(A)$.

$\fbox{$\implies$}$

Assume $\sigma(A)\ne\emptyset$.

Take $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$. Then there exists $x \in V$, $x\ne 0$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$. Extend the linearly independent set $\{x\}$ to a basis $\{x, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ of $V$.

The matrix representation of $A$ in this basis is:

$$\left[\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  \lambda & a_{1,2} & \ldots & a_{1,n-1} & a_{1,n} \\
  \hline
  0 & a_{2,2} & \ldots & a_{2,n-1} & a_{2,n}\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
  0 & a_{n-1,2} & \ldots & a_{n-1,n-1} & a_{n-1,n}\\
  0 & a_{n,2} & \ldots & a_{n,n-1} & a_{n,n}
\end{array}\right]$$

Is there a way to transform $[\{x_2, \ldots, x_n\}]$ to an invariant subspace (so that the first row has zeroes after $\lambda$)?

**Another attempt:**

Consider the standard inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $$\sigma(A^T) = \sigma(A^*) = \overline{\sigma(A)} = \sigma(A)$$ we have $\lambda \in \sigma(A^T)$. Pick $w \ne 0$ such that $A^T w = \lambda w$.

We claim that $\{w\}^\perp$ is $A$-invariant:

Take $y \in \{w\}^\perp$. We have:

$$\langle Ay,w\rangle = \langle y,A^T w\rangle = \langle y,\lambda w\rangle = \lambda \langle y,w\rangle = 0$$

This implies $Aw \in \{w\}^\perp$.

Since $\dim \{w\}^\perp = n-1$, we have found the desired subspace.

Is my proof correct? Is there a way to finish $\fbox{$\implies$}$ without introducing the inner product?

Comment: Instead of $A z = a_{n,n} z$ we have that $Az = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_{i,n} w_i + a_{n,n} z$, so $z$ is not necessarily an eigenvector for $A$.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner I made a stupid mistake. Thank you. Another idea for $\fbox{$\implies$}$ could be to show that $W^\perp$ is $A$-invariant: take $x \in W^\perp$. For $w\in W$ we have: $\langle Ax,w\rangle = \langle x,A^Tw\rangle$. However, we cannot conclude that $A^Tw \in W$, not with the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Perhaps we could choose an inner product which guarantees that $A$ is a normal matrix with respect to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

1. The spectrum of $A$ and $A^{t}$ are the same.
2. $A$ has an invariant $n-1$ dim subspace if and only if $A^{t}$ has an invariant $1$ dim subspace.

You don't need the inner product, just transpose some equality $A = U B U^{-1}$.

Comment: I have proven that if $M$ is $A$-invariant, then $M^\perp$ is $A^t$-invariant. So this would pretty much be a proof: $\lambda \in \sigma(A) \iff \lambda \in \sigma(A^t) \iff [\{\lambda\}]$ is $A^t$-invariant $\iff [\{\lambda\}]^\perp$ is $A$-invariant $\iff$ there exists an $(n-1)$-dimensional $A$-invariant subspace of $V$ (as every $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace is an orthogonal of $[\{\alpha\}]$, for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: So $V$ has to be real to avoid the complex conjugation of $\sigma(A) = \overline{\sigma(A^*)}$? And, could you please clarify how can this be done without the inner product? What is $A = U B U^{-2}$?

Comment: I don't see why you need complex numbers here. This is all over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid: i corrected the ttypo, it's just matrix conjugation. Note, all is done over $\mathbb{R}$. Forget conjugates, you don't need complex numbers here.

Comment: I know, I was just wondering why the problem was stated with $\mathbb{R}$. It seems that the same argument would pass with $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid: indeed, it would work with any field. Somehow for $\mathbb{C}$ it wouldn't say that much, since there is always a complex eigenvalue. But still, the proof works the same. You don't need a hermitian product, just a regular inner product. Yep, over any field.

Comment: How to prove your statement $(2)$ only with matrix conjugation, without inner products and orthogonals?

Comment: @mechanodroid: use the usual transpose, it's easy to see that the spectrum is the same for $A$ and $A^t$. It goes like this : $A$ has an invariant $n-1$ subspace $\iff$ $A^t$ has an invariant $1$ subspace $\iff$ the spectrum of $A^t$  in $F$ is no void $\iff$ the spectrum of $A$ is ....

Comment: Yes, I know that $\sigma(A) = \sigma(A^t)$, since they are conjugate. The part which is troubling me is: $A$ has an invariant $n-1$ subspace $\iff A^t$ has an invariant 1 subspace. I'll think about it some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65393/discussion-between-orangeskid-and-mechanodroid).

Comment: @mechanodroid: if $W$ is invariant under $A$ then $W^t$ is invariant under $A^t$. You define $W^t$ as those vectors whose inner product with vector in $W$ is $0$. Yep, the inner product works for every field. No need for positivity and such things.